# XMPP Openfire Connection Refused

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am using `Openfire` server its admin panel is running on my localhost. When i try to connect to it using android smack library on localhost, port 5222 it gives me Connection Error.

The credentials i am using is...

```
private static final String DOMAIN = "127.0.0.1";
private static final String USERNAME = "admin";
private static final String PASSWORD = "admin";
```

The Exception I am getting is...

**SMACKException: The following addresses failed: '127.0.0.1:5223' failed because java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 5223) after 30000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)**

However I have just installed `openfire` and then set it up. I can see the Admin panel on **http://localhost:9090/** and can login using username and password as admin.

I tried google it but nothing seems like working for me. So can anyone help me to get it working? I am pretty new to `openfire` server so have very little knowledge about it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you connecting to port 5222?

SMACKException: The following addresses failed: '127.0.0.1:5223' failed because java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 5223) after 30000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Your stack point to 5223 (SSL) port.
Also, you have to use your public IP instead of localhost.

```
synchronized void configureConnection() {
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration
            .builder();

    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    config.setServiceName(HOST);
    config.setHost(HOST);
    config.setPort(PORT);
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptiodDefault(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
    connection.addSyncStanzaListener(this, new StanzaTypeFilter(org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message.class));
}
```

Comment: i have tried connecting both. but both of them are giving me same error.

Comment: I will edit my answer with the code that i use to connect in my application

Comment: Do you disabled the SecurityMode? Do you try to open your openfire admin and in Server Configurantion / Client Connections / Plain-text (with STARTTLS) connections / Advanced Settings
And set STARTTLS policy to disable?

Comment: i got it working. thanks :) but i created one user named abc and password as qwerty now when m trying to connect using this credentials it shows authentication failure.. can you suggest me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: i have created new user through Users-> Create new User. but cant login from my android app

Comment: Do you tried to do the things i said in the last comment ?

Comment: yes, and then i made a new user, i can connect it through the spark using the user name and password but when i try to connect through the app it shows me authentication failure.

Answer (score 1):

please check:

1. Did you open 5222 and 5223 port on your openfire server? I've got "Can not connect" error like you, everythings is okay, but I didn't open 5222 and 5223 port to allow connect.
2. Check again the security configuration on your server to set the right config on client

   config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);

Answer (score 0):

hi i have implemented xmpp and below github link have example.Try to follow up thing.

https://github.com/saveendhiman/XMPPSample_Studio

here, you are missing according to me.You have to mention port number.Specified for xmpp is 5222.

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST1,
            5222);
    SmackConfiguration.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
    SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("MD5", 0);
    System.setProperty("smack.debugEnabled", "true");
    config.setCompressionEnabled(false);
    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
    config.setSendPresence(true);
    config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true);
```

Try this,Still you got any error or exception then tell me.

Thank you hope this will help you.

Comment: i have done that, the thing is i am unable to login, after creating a new user when i try to login it shows authentication failure. but if i use that credentials in the spark it got connects.

Comment: ok that good. If you get any issue you can refer above code that is written my me. So i can help you any kind of issue.